# how to get status of all table record without add status field in json data?

Tags: arrays, json, checkbox, angular6, angular7

i want these..!

1. when i click on submit button than get following type of data:
   {

   "name": "bhavesh",
     "sttus": "true or false"
   }

in above object status is true if check box is checked otherwise false.

object :

> tabledsta = [
>       {
>         "id": "1",
>         "name": "bhavesh",
>         "number": "9104198297"
>       },
>       {
>         "id": "2",
>         "name": "mihir",
>         "number": "9154178297"
>       }
>     ];

```html
<table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>id</th>
          <th>name</th>
          <th>number</th>
          <th>select</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let data of tabledsta">
          <td>{{data.id}}</td>
          <td >{{data.name}}</td>
          <td>{{data.number}}</td>
          <td>            
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" (change)="handleSelected($event, data.name)"> Select
          </td>
        </tr>        
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="submitBtn()">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this would be to create and initialize your `resultsArray` with `name` (from the `tabledsta` array) & sttus (initialized to false - since all check-boxes will be marked off); Then on each change of the state of the checkbox, you update your `resultsArray`... this is in the format that you're looking for & displayed on screen for reference also.

relevant **HTML**:

```
<table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>number</th>
                <th>select</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let data of tabledsta">
                <td>{{data.id}}</td>
                <td>{{data.name}}</td>
                <td>{{data.number}}</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" (change)="handleSelected($event, data.name)"> Select
          </td>
        </tr>        
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="submitBtn()">Submit</button>

    <hr/> 
    <b>result: </b> <br/>
    {{ resultsArray | json }}
```

relevant **TS**:

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  tabledsta = [{ "id": "1", "name": "bhavesh", "number": "9104198297" }, { "id": "2", "name": "mihir", "number": "9154178297" }];
  resultsArray: any[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.tabledsta.length; i++) {
      this.resultsArray.push({ name: this.tabledsta[i].name, sttus: false })
    }
  }

  handleSelected(event, dataName) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.resultsArray.length; i++) {
      if (dataName == this.resultsArray[i].name) { this.resultsArray[i].sttus = event.currentTarget.checked };
    }
  }
  submitBtn() {
    //do submit stuff
  }

}
```

complete [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vxut2j)